# Regex python help for coordinate format

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a program that takes the input in a particular format:
example "(1,2)(2,3)(4,3)". They are coordinates and there can be infinitely many coordinates "(1,2)(2,3)(4,3)...(a,b)". I'm writing a function "checkFormat(str)" that returns true if the format is satisfied. I've tried writing a function without the use of regex but it proved too difficult. Need help with the regex expression.

Comment: Wouldn't `\(\d,\d\)` do?

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if it was not work or need any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `^` and `$` to match the whole input. in between is one or more set of `(...)` filled with digits.
Assuming coordinates are integer and no extra space in between:

```
^((\((\d)+\,(\d)+)\))+$
```

if `+/-` is allowed and `0` has no sign and could not be extended (`00` or `01` not accepted)

```
^(\(([-\+]?[1-9]\d*|0)\,(([-\+]?[1-9]\d*)|0)\))+$
```

If decimal numbers are included:

```
^(\(([-\+]?[1-9]\d*|0)([.]\d+)?\,(([-\+]?[1-9]\d*)|0)([.]\d+)?\))+$
```

To check if the input match or not:

```python
import re
pattern=r'^(\(([-\+]?[1-9]\d*|0)([.]\d+)?\,(([-\+]?[1-9]\d*)|0)([.]\d+)?\))+$'
input='(0,2)(1,2)'
result=bool(re.match(pattern,input))
```